# How to get specific word from string

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

How to get specific word from string array ?

```
let array= [
  'age 19 - Donna',
  'age 20 - James'
];
let getNumber = [] //19 and 20
let getName= [] // Donna and James
for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
 getNumber[i] = text[i].split(" ", 2)[1];
  getName[i] = text[i].split(",", 5);
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = getNumber;
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = getName;
```

current result:

> 19,20
>
> age 19 - Donna,age 20 - James

desired result:

> 19,20
>
> Donna,James

Comment: Why are you splitting by comma? There is no comma in the string.

Comment: [Code samples](/help/mcve) should be minimal, *complete* and *representative*. The posted sample refers to but does not define some identifiers and doesn't produce the given output. Please look over the [help], especially the "[ask]" article, and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/90527)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with a [a regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) might be a little simpler.

```js
const demo = document.getElementById('demo');
const demo2 = document.getElementById('demo2');

const array = [
  'age 19 - Donna',
  'age 20 - James'
];

const getNumber = [];
const getName= [];

// Create a regex that picks up a group of numbers
// and a group of letters
const re = /(\d+) - ([a-zA-Z]+)/;

for (let str of array) {

  // `match` on the string with the regex,
  // destructuring the number from the first group
  // and the name from the second group
  const [ , number, name ] = str.match(re);

  // Push the values into the arrays
  getNumber.push(number);
  getName.push(name);
}

demo.textContent = getNumber;
demo2.textContent = getName;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
<div id="demo2"></div>
```

Additional documentation

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 0):

`split` return array, so catch your desire result based on index of that array.

Example:

```js
let array = [
  'age 19 - Donna',
  'age 20 - James'
];

let getNumber = [] //19 and 20
let getName = [] // Donna and James

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  let val = array[i];
  getNumber[i] = val.split(" ")[1];
  getName[i] = val.split(" ")[3];
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = getNumber;
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = getName;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
<div id="demo2"></div>
```